# NoSuchMethodException SoapUI Java

Tags: java, exception, soapui

I am currently writing a Java program that uses SOAPUI api for testing requests. After downloading and adding the soapui-4.5.1.jar to the classpath, I'm getting a NoSuchMethodException exception.

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.eviware.soapui.config.ProjectConfig.setActiveEnvironment(Ljava/lang/String;)V
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlProject.setActiveEnvironment(WsdlProject.java:444)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlProject.<init>(WsdlProject.java:308)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlProject.<init>(WsdlProject.java:212)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlProject.<init>(WsdlProject.java:202)
at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlProject.<init>(WsdlProject.java:187)
at soap.WsdlRequest.testRequest(WsdlRequest.java:17)
at soap.WsdlRequest.main(WsdlRequest.java:45)
```

I looked at the com.eviware.soapui.config.ProjectConfig class, and it has a setActiveEnvironment method. I'm wondering if I'm using the right version of soapui.

Answer (score 0):

Perpahps you have multiple soapui jars in your lib [irrespective of same version] Take a look at the answer here
[How can I catch a NoSuchMethodException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832819/how-can-i-catch-a-nosuchmethodexception)

or it may be a private method. Not sure about this though :)